# Passive version control for Windows

Tags: windows, version-control

I have moved to a new position where non-programmers sometimes produce snips of code and I have been authorized to better structure their code foundation. 
However, before I introduce them to a standard version control system, I would like a passive version control system as a stopgap solution so we experience less losses from now on.

I have experience in programming, version control, and Linux or Windows systems administration, however they do not.

I want to know if there is a tool that can monitor a windows shared folder, and on each file change, passively commit the change to a separate repository.

Principles:

- Being a stopgap, something is better than nothing
- Completely transparent to the user
- Can be a kludge
- Preferably SVN or at least using one of the following: CVS, SVN, Git, Mercurial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CVS like the ones you mention and set up some background auto-commit. E.g. with [git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/420172/395857) on Linux

```
inotifywait -q -m -e CLOSE_WRITE --format="git commit -m 'autocommit on change' %w" file.txt | sh
```

commits file.txt as soon as it is saved. Alternatively, you can [cron the commit](http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/svnautocommit/).

Since each user has their own repository, there shouldn't be any conflict and committing should be smooth, so it kludge shouldn't break often.

Comment: OP mentions "a windows shared folder". I wonder is there a way to do this in Windows?